# Linux popen and system can not be used in Multithreading？

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, system, popen

I want to use popen or system in multithreading to execute my program, pass a parameter to the program and get its output. But I found that I use multithreading to call the same time (very long) as a single-threaded call. Is there any good way?

```
void * _multi_threaded_call(void *arg){
    char *param = (char *)arg;    
    call_my_program(param);
    return NULL;
}


    //buff is the parameter that my 

         if(pthread_create(&tid[thread_id], NULL, &_multi_threaded_call, &buff) == -1){
                printf("fail to create pthread");
                exit(1);
            }
            if(pthread_join(tid[thread_id] , NULL) == -1){
                printf("fail to join pthread");
                exit(1);
            }
```

finally, I use popen, I can't stand a long time, Do you have any good ways? thx :)

```
FILE *fp = popen(cmd, "r");
```

Comment: Well, creating a thread and immediately waiting for it to finish is not going to be effective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I will try it and can the thread really execute the program?  I also thought that the thread is part of the process. In terms of memory, the thread is not allowed to create a new process. Because there is a fork() in the popen(), it is a bit confusing. :)

Comment: regarding: `if(pthread_create(&tid[thread_id], NULL, &_multi_threaded_call, &buff) == -1){`  1) do not prepend a underscore to symbol names, especially if the first letter of the symbol is capitalized.  2) when getting the address of a function, do NOT prepend the function name with `&`

Comment: Multithreading is not a magic bullet. All it allows is multiple threads of execution of code within the same process. Now, both `popen()` and `system()` are thread-safe. However, whatever they execute will take the same time whether the caller is multithreaded or single-threaded. It seems like OP is thinking that adding spectators to a contest will cause the competitors to run faster. No, multithreading does not work like that: you need to change or enhance the competitors to get them to run faster. The spectators don't affect the outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and it is very helpful to me. I can strongly feel the friendship of this community.